# Firewall Rules, IP address failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover

We are having issues with some applications running and connecting to a failover cluster through a firewall (not Windows firewall). In the firewall settings we configure the IP addresses from the failover cluster.

My question is: To which IP address from the failover cluster do we have to connect to?

- The instance IP address (example: server1)
- The a node (active) (example: server1a)
- The b node (passive)(example: server1b)
- the SQL Server listener IP (example: server1-fc)

At the moment we have all of the above configured in the firewall but this is giving performance issues. Why is adding all IP addresses giving performance issues?

This is Basic FCL (not Always On). Is it possible that when we added the instance IP address  (example: server1) in the firewall together with the SQL Server listener (example: server1-fc) it causes the traffic to use/route the wrong IP address?

We started having performance issues when we changed firewall rules. Before the change we had the SQL Server listener configured in the firewall. After the change we added all of the above IP addresses. But why is adding more IP addresses in the firewall causing performance issues?

Comment: You should only connect to your Listener IP.